# Picklist Value Validation Error Not Showing On Page Layout (Not Visualforce)

Tags: formula, picklist

I cannot find a duplicate of this question. I have a picklist value with selections that follow this format:

> "d. the cat is in the hat"

If the user picks this option, they must update another text field to explain *why* they picked this option.

Why doesn't my validation error trigger an error message that shows my error message? Here is my validation:

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL( cat__c ,"d. the cat is in the hat"),
ISBLANK( cat_Other__c ))
```

I'm reading that if the picklist field and options are selected, and the other text field is blank, my condition is true and the error should show.

This isn't Visualforce, it's just a page layout. My validation is active and should show on the field. Nothing shows.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The validation logic on its face appears to be valid. Are you certain that the value stored in the database for your picklist is the same as what you've typed?

To check, you can open the developer console and run a basic SOQL query on a record with the picklist value, e.g.:

SELECT Id, Cat__c FROM Object  WHERE Id = <id>

Where <id> is the Salesforce ID of a record in which Cat__c is "d. the cat is in the hat".

If you find that the value stored in the DB is different from what's in your validation rule, try changing your rule to match what's stored in the DB.

Comment: I have some doubts as to how "d. cat in the hat is stored". Although this is for a new feature that doesn't have records yet. I am testing as a user. I will try this workaround.